# Replacing node request.post with request-promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

**I have:**
I used Node.js request module to get authorization token:

*Working code without promise*

```
var request = require('request');
var querystring = require('querystring');

var requestOpts = querystring.stringify({
    client_id: 'Subtitles',
    client_secret: 'X............................s=',
    scope: 'http://api.microsofttranslator.com',
    grant_type: 'client_credentials'
});

request.post({
    encoding: 'utf8',
    url: "https://datamarket.accesscontrol.windows.net/v2/OAuth2-13",
    body: requestOpts
}, function(err, res, body) { //CALLBACK FUNCTION
    var token = JSON.parse(body).access_token;
    amkeAsyncCall(token);
});
```

**I want:**
It takes some time to get that token. In turn I need `makeAsyncCall` from getToken  callback. So I decide to use a `request-promise` from [here](https://www.npmjs.org/package/request-promise).

**Problem:** request-promise seems don't work for me at all.

**The same (not working) code with promise:**

```
    var rp = require('request-promise');
    var querystring = require('querystring');

    var requestOpts = {
        encoding: 'utf8',
        uri: 'https://datamarket.accesscontrol.windows.net/v2/OAuth2-13',
        method: 'POST',
        body: querystring.stringify({
            client_id: 'Subtitles',
            client_secret: 'Xv2Oae6Vki4CnYcSF1SxSSBtO1x4rX47zhLUE/OqVds=',
            scope: 'http://api.microsofttranslator.com',
            grant_type: 'client_credentials'
        })
    };

    rp(requestOpts)
    .then(function() {
        console.log(console.dir);
    })
    .catch(function() {
        console.log(console.dir);
    });
```

Comment: Any promise library would do, you don't need a whole package for that. Just use `bluebird` and do `Promise.promisify(require("request"))` and it'd work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the node.js package "unirest".

```
var unirest = require('unirest');
var dataObj = {};
var Request = unirest.post('http://127.0.0.1:' + port + '/test/4711DE/de');
Request.headers({ 'Accept': 'application/json' })                    
 .type('json')
 .send(JSON.stringify(dataObj))
 .auth({
   user: 'USERNAME',
   pass: 'PASSWORD',
   sendImmediately: true
 })
 .end(function (response) {
   assert.equal(200, response.statusCode);
   // ...
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

I tested your code with the latest version of [Request-Promise](https://www.npmjs.org/package/request-promise) (0.3.1) and it works fine.

Just the last part of logging to the console was not correct. Use:

```
rp(requestOpts)
    .then(function(body) {
        console.dir(body);
    })
    .catch(function(reason) {
        console.dir(reason);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You could set the `json` attribute in `requestOpts` be `true`, it **works** for me.

```
var rp = require('request-promise');
var querystring = require('querystring');
var requestOpts = {
    encoding: 'utf8',
    uri: 'https://datamarket.accesscontrol.windows.net/v2/OAuth2-13',
    method: 'POST',
    json: true,
    body:    {
        client_id: 'Subtitles',
        client_secret: 'Xv2Oae6Vki4CnYcSF1SxSSBtO1x4rX47zhLUE/OqVds=',
        scope: 'http://api.microsofttranslator.com',
        grant_type: 'client_credentials'
    }
};

rp(requestOpts)
.then(function() {
    console.log(console.dir);
})
.catch(function() {
    console.log(console.dir);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue I just added this property
`headers = { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' };`

```
var requestOpts = {
    encoding: 'utf8',
    uri: 'https://datamarket.accesscontrol.windows.net/v2/OAuth2-13',
    method: 'POST',
    headers = { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' };
    body: JSON.stringify({
        client_id: 'Subtitles',
        client_secret: 'Xv2Oae6Vki4CnYcSF1SxSSBtO1x4rX47zhLUE/OqVds=',
        scope: 'http://api.microsofttranslator.com',
        grant_type: 'client_credentials'
    })
};
```

Comment: options can parse to JSON if you add `json: true,` see https://github.com/request/request#requestoptions-callback.